# Can I display a native login view while PhoneGap loads on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-asynctask, sencha-touch-2

I'm currently working on a Sencha 2 application that is taking a long time to launch. The first screen is always a login form, so I'd like to make that native and enable the user to start entering their credentials while the web-based `Activity` loads.

I found posts describing `AsyncTask` (or `AsyncTaskLoader`), but I'm not just loading data. I need to instantiate a full `WebView` along with all the included JavaScript and DOM assets. Is this possible (with an `AsyncTask` or otherwise), and are there any good online examples?

Of note, I'm targeting Android 2.2 or later, and my main `Activity` is currently a subclass of PhoneGap/Cordova's `DroidGap` (though we don't use the PhoneGap plugins, so it doesn't need to be). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need `AsyncTask`. I just used a `PopupWindow` and attached that to the `root` view created by `DroidGap`:

```
private PopupWindow popup;
private MyCustomOverlayView overlay;

@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    super.init();
    super.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/www/index.html" );

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    overlay = new MyCustomOverlayView( getContext() );
    popup = new PopupWindow( overlay, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), true );
    root.post( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            popup.showAtLocation( root, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0 );
        }
    } );
}
```